# How Sharepoint discussion board works

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can any one say me how the sharepoint discussion board work. my exact requirement is when we add reply for the new discussion the body field contain the old previous post  content . can any one explain me how its possible to do .

Regards,

Zakeer Ahamed.S

Answer (score 1):

it is default behavior of Discussion Board (see below)
[image]

Comment: hi Ivan, Thanks for the screen shot is that possible for me to add a custom field of same type(multiple type) and name it as description and the newly added fields should also have the same behaviour as body field have.

Comment: you need to put some customizations to a new form to get similar behavior with your custom columns